# Hive: Optimal way to JOIN using 2 ON conditions with NULL

Tags: sql, join, hive, left-join

I have 2 tables which look as below.

Table_A

```
ID1  ID2  NAME
112  NULL ADAM
132  990  BRIAN
NULL 980  CARL
```

Table_B

```
ID1  ID2  SURNAME
112  NULL LEVINE
132  990  LARA
NULL 980  JOHNSON
```

If I join the table as below the null comparisons would not work and hence not return a surname for ADAM

```
SELECT A.NAME,B.SURNAME
FROM
TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_B B
ON A.ID1 = B.ID1
AND
A.ID2 = B.ID2;
```

I added a check for NULL in the ON clause for ID2 which did work but the operation turned out to be costly for even small tables. (See below)

```
SELECT A.NAME,B.SURNAME
FROM
TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_B B
ON 
(A.ID1 = B.ID1 OR (A.ID1 IS NULL AND B.ID1 IS NULL))
AND
(A.ID2 = B.ID2 OR (A.ID2 IS NULL AND B.ID2 IS NULL));
```

What would be the right way to go about with this comparison?

Comment: Try to use `COALESCE` for ID field to change `NULL` with non-empty value: `ON COALESCE(A.ID1, '_NULL_') = COALESCE(B.ID1, '_NULL_') AND ...`

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical case scenario that calls for a NULL-safe equality operator, which is natively supported by Hive with the GenericUDF `<=>`. This operator, as I quote:

```
Returns same result with EQUAL(=) operator for non-null operands, 
but returns TRUE if both are NULL, FALSE if one of the them is NULL.
```

So the SQL is as simple as the following:

```
select 
    a.name,
    b.surname
from table_a a
left join table_b b
on a.id1 <=> b.id1 and a.id2 <=> b.id2;
```

Answer (score 1):

To join NULLs like normal values, use `NVL()` function to substitute `NULL` with some value which is not used normally in the data, for example `-9999`:

```
SELECT A.NAME,B.SURNAME
FROM
TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_B B
ON NVL(A.ID1,-9999) = NVL(B.ID1,-9999)
AND
NVL(A.ID2,-9999) = NVL(B.ID2,-9999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't support `or` expression in `on` condition.
The join condition should consists of `purely equality expression`.

I prefer the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT A.NAME,B.SURNAME
FROM
TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_B B
ON 
 COALESCE(A.ID1, 'missing') = COALESCE(B.ID1, 'missing') 
AND
 COALESCE(A.ID2, 'missing') = COALESCE(B.ID2, 'missing')
```